# How to add a new buffer to opening nvim-qt instead of opening a new instance on Windows?

Tags: neovim

I have set up nvim-qt version 06 on my Windows 10 to use it instead of notepad++.
And when I double-click on a file, a new nvim-qt instance will open.
But now, what I want is if I double-click on a file, nvim-qt will open a new buffer in running nvim-qt instead of opening a new nvim-qt instance. It will save me a lot of time.
Do you know any way to do that? please help

Thanks,

Comment: Here is a link to a solution I have proposed on Vi and Vim: [How can I use --servername and --remote in Neovim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25187/23502)